# css Visiblity issue in magento CE

Tags: html, css, magento, visibility

i need to hide a div 
this is my html

```
<div class="text">
    <div class="active">text</div>
    <div>text2</div>
</div>
```

and this is my css

```
.text div 
{
visibility:hidden !important;
}
.active 
{
visibility:visible !important;    
}
```

i have to hide the div with text2 ( i cant assign class or id to it ) but in the same time i have to show the div with text (i.e. with class active)

**My limitations**

1. i have to use !important as i need to override my CSS which i receiving via CDN
2. i cant assign any additional id or class to the the DIVs

I am able to hide all the divs but i also need to show div with class active

Comment: use `div.active` instead of just `.active`. Keep in mind that it is not a good practice though.

Comment: Try `display:none` to hide and `display:block` to show.

Comment: @Mr_Green thanks it works [link](http://jsfiddle.net/PP3Du/) can you elaborate why it is not a good practice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

CSS :

```
 .text div 
    {
    visibility:hidden !important;
    }
    .text .active 
    {
    visibility:visible !important;    
    }
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="text">
        <div class="active">text</div>
        <div>text2</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: is this a good practice ?? As mr_green suggested a solution and said that its not a good